# Error related to angular2-datatable compatible with Ivy

Tags: datatable, ivy, angular13

I am using angular2-datatable version 0.6.0 in my angular application which used
Angular Version 2.
We upgraded Angular to use 13.2.0 recently, the application build and compiles successfully.
But I see some console error when I did ng serve.
The errors are related to  angular2-datatable saying that is is not compatible with Ivy.
The error is shown below.

Error: node_modules/angular2-datatable/lib/DataTableModule.d.ts:1:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of XXXXXXX, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (angular2-datatable) which declares DataTableModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

I see the latest version of angular2-datatable is 0.6.0.
I tried changing "aot": true or false in Angular.json file and also modified  "enableIvy" property in tsconfig.json to true or false, nothing seems to clear those errors.

Any clue on how to resolve this..

Answer (score 0):

In `angular.json` setting both `buildOptimizer` and `aot` properties to `false` did the job for me.